# Force reduced width of comparison instructions

Tags: llvm

I want to force LLVM to generate `CMPx`-, `TEST`- and alike instructions on x86-64 to be up to 8 bit width only, forcing e.g. 32bit-int comparisons into four separate cmp+branch pairs. This obviously requires some bit-masking and increased instruction count.
Can I achieve this by simply "disabling" certain instructions for x86-64 so LLVM auto-generates the required glue code? Do I have to write a pass and work on the IR myself?

Comment: My speculative guess would be you'd have to do this yourself - why would LLVM have a mode to emit intentionally suboptimal machine code?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way of disabling certain instructions like this from a vanilla build of LLVM. Anything you do to achieve this will require modifying LLVM.

You have several options for modifying LLVM:

1. You can add an x86-specific pass to the LLVM *backend* (does not work on the IR) which directly expands the `cmp` and `test` instructions into chains of instructions on sub-registers. You would have to do this after instruction selection to preclude some target-independent pass from undoing the transformation. This is called an "MI" pass in LLVM parlance. As an example you can look in `X86FixupSetCC.cpp` ([mirror here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/lib/Target/X86/X86FixupSetCC.cpp)). This has a huge advantage in that you can put it behind a flag and otherwise control whether it occurs once you add the core functionality.
2. You can modify LLVM's instruction tables for LLVM in the [X86 .td files](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/lib/Target/X86/X86.td) to only define these instructions for 8-bit registers, and then add the `def Pat<...>;` patterns to the .td files that allow programs with wider comparisons to still have their instructions selected (much as Colin suggested above). This has the disadvantage of not only have you modified your LLVM but you can't easily turn those modifications on and off behind some flag.

You can't do anything to LLVM's IR that will really help here because the code generator will just optimize things back into instruction patterns you're trying to avoid.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

What you're probably looking to do is redefine the lowering pattern in the x86 .td files.  There's code that looks like "def Pat<...>;" that defines a translation from one graph of instructions to another. There should be a pattern for going from IR comparison instructions to the x86 32bit compare instructions. You'll want to edit this pattern and instead output your sequence of comparisons.

Comment: Which would leave me with a custom-built llvm - is possible to implement this as a pass?

Comment: You can change the IR level comparisons with a pass but the backend is still free to expand it if it wants, I don't know how it's implemented. If your requirement is for specific X86 instructions the only way to assure that is with changes to instruction lowering.